# OpenCart - function addToCart / no success message / no cart refresh

Tags: javascript, message, opencart

I have a problem with a custom template, as after i add a product to the cart, no confirmation is displayed.In detail, after adding a product nothing happens and for example the cart information in the header stays empty. (See picture one)

http://de.tinypic.com/r/2hozei0/8

After clicking on the empty cart suddenly the product appears. (See picture two)
So its seems that the success message and the cart refresh is missing after adding a product.

http://i58.tinypic.com/20zcl6g.png

Figured it out that the needed handling appears in **catalog/view/javascript/common.js**

Functions like "addToWishList" or "addToCompare" are working but the "addToCart" is NOT working.

```
function addToCart(product_id, quantity) {
quantity = typeof(quantity) != 'undefined' ? quantity : 1;

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        $('.success, .warning, .attention, .information, .error').remove();

        if (json['redirect']) {
            location = json['redirect'];
        }

        if (json['success']) {
            $('#notification').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');

            $('.success').fadeIn('slow');

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
        }   
    }
});}
```

Any help appreciated! I am using OC 1.5.6

Regards!

---

see my **/template/common/header.tpl**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="<?php echo $direction; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<base href="<?php echo $base; ?>" />
<?php if ($description) { ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($keywords) { ?>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($icon) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $icon; ?>" rel="icon" />
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach ($links as $link) { ?>
<link href="<?php echo $link['href']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $link['rel']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/cloud-zoom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/slideshow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/jquery.prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php foreach ($styles as $style) { ?>
<link rel="<?php echo $style['rel']; ?>" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $style['href']; ?>" media="<?php echo $style['media']; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/external/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template'); ?>/stylesheet/skin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/colorbox/colorbox.css" media="screen" />
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Krona+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4-iefix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]><div style='clear:both;height:59px;padding:0 15px 0 15px;position:relative;z-index:10000;text-align:center;'><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a></div><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/easyTooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jQuery.equalHeights.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="catalog/view/javascript/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jscript_zjquery.anythingslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery.bxSlider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<?php foreach ($scripts as $script) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $script; ?>"></script>
<?php } ?>
<!--[if  IE 8]>
    <style>
        .success, #header #cart .content  { border:1px solid #e7e7e7;}
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if  IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/ie6.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
DD_belatedPNG.fix('#logo img');
</script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/<?php echo $this->config->get('config_template');?>/stylesheet/livesearch.css"/>
<?php if ($stores) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).ready(function() {
<?php foreach ($stores as $store) { ?>
$('body').prepend('<iframe src="<?php echo $store; ?>" style="display: none;"></iframe>');
<?php } ?>
});
//--></script>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $google_analytics; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php echo empty($this->request->get['route']) ? 'common-home' : str_replace('/', '-', $this->request->get['route']); ?>">
<div class="bg-1">
<div class="main-shining">
<div class="row-1">
<div id="header">
    <div class="toprow">
        <div class="outer1">

            <?php echo $currency; ?>
            <div id="welcome">
                <?php if (!$logged) { ?>
                <?php echo $text_welcome; ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php echo $text_logged; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
                <?php echo $telephone; ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $language; ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer1">
    <?php if ($logo) { ?>
    <div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="header-top1"> 
        <div id="search">
            <div class="button-search"></div>
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo $text_search; ?>" value="<?php echo $search; ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="cart-position">
            <div class="cart-inner"><?php echo $cart; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="topmenu">
            <ul class="links">
                <?php if (!isset($this->request->get['route'])) { $route='active'; }  else {$route='';}?> <li class="first"><a class="<?php echo $route; if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route']=="common/home") {echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route']=="account/wishlist") {echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route']=="account/account") {echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $account; ?>"><?php echo $text_account; ?></a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route']=="checkout/cart") {echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $shopping_cart; ?>"><?php echo $text_shopcart; ?></a></li>
                <li><a class="<?php if (isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route']=="checkout/checkout") {echo "active";} ?>" href="<?php echo $checkout; ?>"><?php echo $text_checkout; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="menu">
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.menu ul li').last().addClass('last');
                $('.menu ul li li').last().addClass('last');
            });

        </script>
  <?php if ($categories) { ?>
  <ul  class="menu">
    <?php $cv=0;?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { $cv++; ?>
    <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
    <li class="active cat_<?php echo $cv ?>">
      <?php } else { ?>
    <li class="cat_<?php echo $cv ?>">
      <?php } ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>

            <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
            <ul>
              <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
              <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
              <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
              <?php $id=$category['children'][$i]['category_id'];?>
              <?php if ( $id == $child_id) { ?>
              <li class="active">
                <?php } else { ?>
              <li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ($category['children'][$i]['children3']) {?>
                <a class="screenshot1"  href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name'];?></a>
                <ul>
                  <?php foreach ($category['children'][$i]['children3'] as $ch3) { ?>
                  <li>
                    <?php if ($ch3['category_id'] == $ch3_id) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $ch3['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $ch3['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $ch3['href']; ?>"><?php echo $ch3['name']; ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                  </li>
                  <?php } ?>
                </ul>
                <?php } else {?>
                <a class="screenshot1"  href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name'];?></a>
              <?php }?>
              </li>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </ul>
            <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php if ($modules) {?>
<div class="header-modules">
  <?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
  <?php echo $module; ?>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php }?>
<div class="main-container">
<p id="back-top"> <a href="#top"><span></span></a> </p>
<div id="container">
<div id="notification"> </div>
```

I think it should be ok, any clue why the functions $('.success').fadeIn('slow'); / $('#cart-total').html(json['total']); are not working?

I tried to change to the default template and the same problem appears, so maybe its no problem with the template?

Comment: Check that custom template and make sure (in `header.tpl`) that these elements are present: DIV with ID notification, DIV with ID cart-total.

Comment: Added header.tpl and comment in inital message

Comment: `<div id="notification"> </div>` is there (at the end) but I cannot find `<div id="cart-total"> </div>` unless it is printed out within `<div class="cart-inner"><?php echo $cart; ?></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add   ,  and   this portion in the header template.